# How to drag a UIView and resize from TopLeftCorner?

Tags: objective-c, resize

How to resize a UIView by dragging the TopLeftCorner, the BottomRightCorner should be fixed.

I am using touchesBegan, touchesMoved methods.
How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same solution and [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8835573/790794) and it is working good for me. I need to do some modifications as per requirements and that's not a big issue. 

Hope it will also work for you!:)