# UIView resizing based on edges

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiview, uitextfield

How to resize `UIView` based on its edges?

Actually I am creating `UITextField` programmatically, and if User want then they can increase and decrease `UITextField's` height and width by dragging its edges..

I do not want to change its height and width proportionally. If user want height then only height changes and if width then only width.

So I found the solution to take One `UIView` programmatically and then place `UITextField` in it..

**So My question is,** How can we change UIView's height and width by touching on UIView's Edges?

I know all about `UIPanGestureRecognizer` but don't want that.

I had gone through [this stackoverw link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460119/how-to-resize-uiview-by-dragging-from-its-edges) and also got [this solution](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/spuserresizableview) but It is not useful for me..

Please suggest me what to do?

**UPDATE**

Currently doing work on [SPUserResizableView](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/spuserresizableview) and I think this will be useful..

Thanks to all my friends..

Comment: Why is the first link not useful? It will implement resizing quite nicely. Is there something more specific you're going for?

Comment: @MilesAlden When you are going with UIPanGestureRecognizer, It will increse width and height proportionally. and I m not going to do that

Comment: @Mehul `UIPanGestureRecognizer` reports both the X and Y offset of the gesture.  But you can just ignore the X offset when the user is dragging the height handle, and ignore the Y offset when the user is dragging the width handle.

Comment: @Mehul Also, you haven't explained *why* `SPUserResizableView` is not useful for you.

Comment: @robmayoff Sry for not updating my question but I am currently trying to use that for the same..

Answer (score -1):

It's simple .
Have you heard about -

```
TouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

TouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

TouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

TouchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

You just need to add this methods in your UIView class.
then from some sort of calculation you can do that.
Say When you touch Touch begain methods get's called ... in Touch move you can move animate for the uiview to increase or decrease height or width.
As All the above function will give you coordinate of x and y.

Hope this may help you.

Comment: I know and It is very simple.. But can u plz elaborate more.. Had you done this ever?