# Move image view by touch, but a little more specific

Tags: ios, imageview, move

I really would like to know how to make an image view move when I touch the screen. Though, I would like specific coordinates to be specific directions.

Imagine breaking up the screen into 9 identical squares, the middle being my image view, the rest being the direction in which they are pointing.

If you see this please don't flag it down, tell me why you want to flag it down and I'll fix it. I've spent over 6 hours trying to find out how to do this. Thanks for your time and consideration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resize UIView by dragging from its edges?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460119/how-to-resize-uiview-by-dragging-from-its-edges)

Comment: No, I want to touch on the right side of the screen(161-320) and have the UIImageView move the exact opposite way.

Comment: not gettin' ur problem.. add me on skype  'mrpatrnogic'