# Setting the Min and Max width and height for resizable UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, ios8

I wanted to make a resizable UIView using touches from corners, and I've found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8835573/4396532) and it worked well. But how can I add the ability to stop resizing when the width/height is 200 for example?

This is the code:

```
CGFloat kResizeThumbSize = 45.0f;

@interface MY_CLASS_NAME : UIView {
BOOL isResizingLR;
BOOL isResizingUL;
BOOL isResizingUR;
BOOL isResizingLL;
CGPoint touchStart;
}
```

And..

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
touchStart = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
isResizingLR = (self.bounds.size.width - touchStart.x < kResizeThumbSize && self.bounds.size.height - touchStart.y < kResizeThumbSize);
isResizingUL = (touchStart.x <kResizeThumbSize && touchStart.y <kResizeThumbSize);
isResizingUR = (self.bounds.size.width-touchStart.x < kResizeThumbSize && touchStart.y<kResizeThumbSize);
isResizingLL = (touchStart.x <kResizeThumbSize && self.bounds.size.height -touchStart.y <kResizeThumbSize);
}

 - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
CGPoint previous = [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView:self];

CGFloat deltaWidth = touchPoint.x - previous.x;
CGFloat deltaHeight = touchPoint.y - previous.y;

// get the frame values so we can calculate changes below
CGFloat x = self.frame.origin.x;
CGFloat y = self.frame.origin.y;
CGFloat width = self.frame.size.width;
CGFloat height = self.frame.size.height;

if (isResizingLR) {
    self.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, touchPoint.x+deltaWidth, touchPoint.y+deltaWidth);
} else if (isResizingUL) {
    self.frame = CGRectMake(x+deltaWidth, y+deltaHeight, width-deltaWidth, height-deltaHeight);
} else if (isResizingUR) {
    self.frame = CGRectMake(x, y+deltaHeight, width+deltaWidth, height-deltaHeight);      
} else if (isResizingLL) {
    self.frame = CGRectMake(x+deltaWidth, y, width-deltaWidth, height+deltaHeight);   
} else {
    // not dragging from a corner -- move the view
    self.center = CGPointMake(self.center.x + touchPoint.x - touchStart.x,
        self.center.y + touchPoint.y - touchStart.y);
}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (isResizingLR) {
   if(touchPoint.x+deltaWidth < 200 && touchPoint.y+deltaWidth < 200)
     self.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, touchPoint.x+deltaWidth, touchPoint.y+deltaWidth);
} else if (isResizingUL) {
   if(width-deltaWidth < 200 && height-deltaHeight < 200)
     self.frame = CGRectMake(x+deltaWidth, y+deltaHeight, width-deltaWidth, height-deltaHeight);
} else if (isResizingUR) {
   if(width+deltaWidth < 200 && height-deltaHeight < 200)
     self.frame = CGRectMake(x, y+deltaHeight, width+deltaWidth, height-deltaHeight);      
} else if (isResizingLL) {
   if(width-deltaWidth < 200 && height+deltaHeight < 200)
      self.frame = CGRectMake(x+deltaWidth, y, width-deltaWidth, height+deltaHeight);   
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
@property(nonatomic) CGRect frame
```

Description The frame rectangle, which describes the view’s location and size in its superview’s coordinate system.

Before setting self.frame with CGRect, check for width and height!

```
CGRect CGRectMake(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat width, CGFloat height);
```

Use width and height for actual size and delta for transformation.