# Swift: CropView for UIImageView

Tags: swift, uiimage, crop

I'm looking for a tutorial to tell me how to create a frame to crop the photo, as the picture below

[image: Sample]

thanks

Comment: As a first step this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/8460119/1244597

Comment: Thank you very much my friend. Put this answer, in normal response and not in comment as it solves!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first step please look into implementing a `UIView` that resizes using the corners/handles. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8460119/1244597) should help

Once we have a resizable `UIView`, then using `UIView.frame`'s origin and size to crop the image, like so:

```
extension UIImage {

    func crop(size: CGSize, offset: CGPoint, scale: CGFloat = 1.0) -> UIImage? {
        let rect = CGRect(x: offset.x * scale, y: offset.y * scale, width: size.width * scale, height: size.height * scale)
        if let cropped = self.cgImage?.cropping(to: rect) {
            return UIImage(cgImage: cropped)
        }
        return nil
    }

}

let croppedImage = image.crop(size: resizableView.frame.size, offset: resizableView.frame.origin)
```