# Resizing text view by dragging its corners (Swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield, autoresize, imglykit

I am new to IOS and currently working for frames and photo-editing app.I am struggling with how to change the size of the UITextView by dragging its corners in swift? It is same as what we see on photo-editing apps for adding text over frames or pictures and resizing/positioning it according to our will.
Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Could you provide more information?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there is no built-in support for that in UIKit.

To build your own custom solution check this out:
[How to resize UIView by dragging from its edges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460119/how-to-resize-uiview-by-dragging-from-its-edges)